# Can't connect to a Windows Share folder that uses a user name and password?

Tags: nautilus, samba, windows-10, shared-folders, nemo

I am trying to connect to a Windows Share folder. I can see it on my network, but when I enter the address of the share folder, for example smb://Server-Raid/OneDrive, I get an error message stating that I do not have permission to access it.

I have set my Windows Share folder to use a username and password in order to be accessed over the network, however I get no option to add it when connecting from my Ubuntu PC (tried Nautilus and Nemo), plus I am not prompted to add any credentials either.

Is there any way I can connect to a Windows Share folder that uses a user name and password? I can connect if I open up the Windows Share folder to 'everyone', however this is not ideal.

I should be getting a prompt from Nautilus when trying to access the Windows share drive, but none shows, I just get the permissions error.

Is there a way to access using terminal command?

I found this work-around [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B8lPKRe0x0&ab_channel=TroubleChute)

Unfortunately, the auto-mount fails too, even though I have created a credentials file and added automount to the fstab.

```
//Server-Raid/OneDrive /home/pst007x/onedrive cifs credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I created a .smbcred with the information (my windows login):

> username=MyUsername
>
> password=MyPassword

I can access fine from other windows PC's, they ask for the credentials, and I can remote in using Remmina.

Error when accessing folder:

> Unable to access 'onedrive'
>
> Mount.Cifs: Permission Denied

Installed Dolphin, opened network, entered Windows share folder address, it asked me for credentials and worked straight away. I think Nautilus is just too broken nowadays. Perhaps KDE is the better route?

Comment: Run the following command to see if it prompts you or if there are any errors:         `gio mount smb://192.168.0.22/ShareFolder`

Comment: If I run in Terminal I get no output, no prompt to add login credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Nautilus will not request credentials when accessing a Windows share folder, if a username and password is required.

Dolphin will work fine.

The only way I found was to do this:

1. Create a text file in your home folder, .smbcred
2. Add your Windows credentials:

> username=YourUsername
>
> password=YourPassword

3. Create a mount directory using Terminal:

   mkdir /home/username/YourMountDirectory
4. In Terminal enter (change details to suit your locations):

   sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcred //192.168.0.62/OneDrive /home/pst007x/onedrive
5. Open the mount folder, remote files should sync there.